# How should I display long code in question?

Tags: discussion, support, questions

For long code, what should I do?

1. write down all the code in body content
2. Parse the snippet and link the rest of it using pastebin
3. post the pastebin URL only.

And, how long is *long*?

Answer (score 9):

If you feel you *need* that much code to ask a question, the question is probably wrong. Or, at least, a bad fit for Stack Overflow.

Comment: I can take conclusion that the better solution / question is, to give short snippet and post the long one on pastebin.

Comment: yes, that is a good compromise -- show the relevant bits and put the rest behind a link.

Answer (score 4):

Ideally you should make it short enough to fit in the normal question length.  I've yet to see a good reason for more than about 80 lines of source in a question on SO.

Answer (score 2):

You should keep the code to the minimum capable to explain your inquiry/problem.

In my experience, *more* than 100 lines is too much.

You should always try to post the smallest possible code showing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It is better to just include the important lines in your code; however, sometimes you can't realize that other parts of the code are relevant too. So, in same cases is good to include the whole code. For that reason I think Stack Overflow should have the option to include an option to attach code in files, or maybe a pastebin like solution.