# How should I show lengthy code on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, code-formatting

I have 5 pages of code as a part of my question. How can show it? I would not be interested to post it as such. Also, it's code generated by a framework. Hence I don't want to edit it. Should I use pastebin or something similar?

Comment: Why do you think anyone wants to wade through 5 pages of code?  Can't you come up with a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)?

Comment: You can [read this possible duplicate](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28102/how-should-i-display-long-code-in-question) along with the question linked to it.

Comment: And if it's code that is generated by a framework, perhaps it's better to share what you put into the generation? (Don't know the exact scenario here, so it might not apply)

Comment: Another possible duplicate: [where to paste large blocks of code / text?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36979/where-to-paste-large-blocks-of-code-text/36982#36982)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

All necessary info of a question should be in the question itself. If the code segment is too big for a Stack Overflow question then the scope of your question is too big as well.

Reduce it to the very core so people don't have to review pages of code.

That takes effort. But we want questions be helpful to future visitors and that can only be possible if one can see the problem with a quick read.

Answer (score 5):

> Also, it's code generated by a framework

In this case, you could describe the framework you used and the parameters you supplied to auto-generate the code. Then other people can reproduce the problem without you needing to post an un-holy amount of code in your question.

It's quite possible your problem has been caused by incorrect use of the framework, which would only be apparent once you explain how you used it.

*(Just noticed [Bart commented on this already](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/202815/how-should-i-show-lengthy-code-on-stack-overflow/202820#comment645311_202815))*

Answer (score 2):

Why you want to show 5 pages of code?

- Is there an issue on the code?

  - If Yes, try to debug and post only "buggy part of the code"
  - If No, don't post it
- If you want to understand the code then refer link of java/.net/php/... site link directly and explain it clearly on the question